# cocos2d SDK, iOS template is missing

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I've installed cocos2d SDK (stable version cocos2d-iphone-2.0.tar.gz) and its templates but just three templates added to my xcode and all for Mac but another option for iOS supposed to be installed, how can I add a template for iOS ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you have not set up the terminal settings

Follow the steps below :

- Open terminal
- Go to your folder where you want to install cocos2d
- write `./install-templates.sh -u`

Cocos2d will install successfully

Enjoy Programming !!

Comment: That's exactly what I've done the problem is that it supposed to intall one template for iOS but now all are about Mac!
I tried unstable version now and it added another option but for 'Chipmunk and CocosBuilder Reader with JavaScript bindings'

Comment: now i tried this version release-2.1-rc1 - cocos2d for iPhone v2.1-rc1 and it works, thanks:)